# ERROR : NoSuchMethodError: The method 'substring' was called on null

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying this certain app (world-time app) and constantly getting this error:

Used this HTTP Package for url:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class WorldTime {
  String location;
  String time;
  String flag;
  String url;

  WorldTime({this.location, this.flag, this.url});

  Future<void> getTime() async {
    try {
      Response response =
          await get(Uri.https('worldtimeapi.org', 'api/timezone/$url'));
      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      String datetime = data['datetime'];
      String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3);

      DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
      now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));

      time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error occured: $e");
      time = "Cannot Display Time Due to Error Occured";
    }
  }
}
```

imported world time api in this file:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:world_time_app/services/world_time.dart';


class loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _loadingState createState() => _loadingState();
}

class _loadingState extends State<loading> {
  void setTime() async {
    WorldTime instance =
        WorldTime(location: 'Florida', flag: 'img.jpg', url: 'America/Florida');
    await instance.getTime();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
      'location' : instance.location,
      'flag': instance.flag,
      'time': instance.time,
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
      child: Text('Loading'),
    ));
  }
}
```

pls help me Im getting error while running the app:

```
Restarted application in 1,228ms.
I/flutter (24197): Error occured: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'substring' was called on null.
I/flutter (24197): Receiver: null
I/flutter (24197): Tried calling: substring(1, 3)
I/flutter (24197): {location: Florida, flag: img.jpg, time: Cannot Display Time Due to Error Occured}
```

I think I made DateTime Object thats why it is showing error, is there any alternative to this?
Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: You are calling this with `url = "America/Florida"`. Did you try look at the result of `https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Florida` for instance in the browser? Its `{"error": "unknown location"}` Thus, obviously `data["utc_offset"]` is null, because there is no property `utc_offset` in the result ... Try using a valid location

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is most likely because `utc_offset` is null.

You can check if it's actually null or not, and that it's length is  at least 3 before performing `substring(1,3)` on it, like this:

```
String offset = 
   data['utc_offset'] == null || data['utc_offset'].length >= 3 
   ? "utc offset has a problem" 
   : data['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3);
```